# how to download private key RSA of aws using php sdk?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, rsa

I have sucessfully integrated the AWS php SDK to create instance, but I am facing problem to download or export key pair "RSA PRIVATE KEY" on my local repository, when I print the array its visible but when I print by its key than it is not showing on the screen and the file are downloaded empty

here is the script of AWS PHP SDK

```
$ec2Client = Ec2Client::factory(array(
        'version'     => 'latest',  
        'region'      => REGION,
        'credentials' => $credentials


));


// Create the key pair
$keyPairName = 'key';
$result = $ec2Client->createKeyPair(array(
    'KeyName' => $keyPairName
));

$saveKeyLocation = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop'. "/.ssh/{$keyPairName}.pem";//getenv('HOME') . "/.ssh/{$keyPairName}.pem";
// Save the public key in public.pem file
file_put_contents($saveKeyLocation, $result['KeyMaterial']);


// Update the key's permissions so it can be used with SSH
chmod($saveKeyLocation, 0600);
```

when I print $result its give me complete array but when I print by its key $result['KeyMaterial'] its empty and also file is downloaded in empty.

here is array of $result

```
Aws\Result Object
(
    [data:Aws\Result:private] => Array
        (
            [KeyFingerprint] => 10:46:e4:73:ec:b7:63:8b:98:20:b4:9d:e3:52:9d:1f:57:65:8c:e0
            [KeyMaterial] => -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAySsM6nbCpYxWtE/Xlyj+heD7lKTFo3KrguLKBiRVIitG1eUx
FfxSSVCFs+ePGfjKTpS96e4ybnr9IiLosTlMBMm81wbtaIR3a1zcenKWrgFI6xyA
mdDwGL2C4e5Ha8pnEQkgXnEbulAlkn3v95wHtIUxIAh1nwCiIMbsk4Q518D7lLUo
fATvyPj3PVHXNvD4K6eI6gWOLUtqLG6MNQI7w0nURoHUqMBsHsVg/Tml8/bCbP8p
................................................................
........................................BQZuKvceZxPGykX5tUSD1LwT
TWekB3MMGaTtW98nNdwOIdMdFDv7PRClzDaaPp7K4YsFiFvuTLq91m8Gsw3uEzpL
sJSJsilmL/jp1IgLm7RwHqq6ev/Y9VADKt/olxMCgYAZFW23pgkqEemhTDI9+q5C
UDup0CAouNASuudJOYxakcUo0mcm2lqAqixXA+W3DvtCHRJdhutWBNk3pYk5Ei6m
ABFQAckNf6.........................................7mSZC7Ck02UDd
l1w/dBpSaRDTqTql00RHyQKBgQC1J2DR7plvKrEFOmW++PIfhL5aI9vW7GeV0D/k
IHDMWovSb+sFF+GQsz3JEYv1ZBlkTajQSEVT8ELFKZC9d4yWtDq1DwRRW/7wECLE
NZAccLUQdAnX0JLk2gG8zKrj0jCeSmSqsj74YKNPVzlbeZjHP2qiUOJcfPXsCRJ1
VuELjwKBgH9J+g7Iukc1OqRZISFOJlmOMqpancjps0ZH/yosmnRusT+x+mrMEvuJ
zs56DzU3rG2asijhntBpEAj5IT0BfxWebh0W0PRxlOSfwxZBcOfwQyLigBFcUerB
USi8kmtydjocjiQBkLShtDTEJ+TfJfkAg2f35mtn/gEvPusNRh19
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
            [KeyName] => mya-keaaaykpair-m1
            [KeyPairId] => key-0a7b8707dd11fbd7f
            [@metadata] => Array
                (
                    [statusCode] => 200
                    [effectiveUri] => https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
                    [headers] => Array
                        (
                            [x-amzn-requestid] => 532daf73-*****-****-b9df-f1b43c4b75d1
                            [content-type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8
                            [content-length] => 2095
                            [vary] => accept-encoding
                            [date] => Thu, 24 Sep 2020 08:36:10 GMT
                            [server] => AmazonEC2
                        )

                    [transferStats] => Array
                        (
                            [http] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [monitoringEvents:Aws\Result:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Kindly let me know how can I resolve it ? Because after successfully downloaded than I will convert into ppk file format by using puttygen

Answer (score 1):

your problem is about your syntax

your element is an object but you get parameters from it by array syntexes

use one the followings:

```
echo($result->KeyMaterial);

// or

echo($result->data->KeyMaterial);
```

and let us known the result

---

*****Edit:*****

as i seen your code, you're using the samples of self docs.aws.amazon.com that they left as pdf on their sites and your codes is very very similar to their samples

but your code has a simple difference and that is you use static "factory" method

if you use the SDK that amazon wroted in [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/aws-sdk-php-v3-developer-guide.pdf) try this code and if not please use it to see do your problem solve or not:

```
$ec2Client = new Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client([
    'region' => REGION,
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
$keyPairName = 'my-keypair';
$result = $ec2Client->createKeyPair(['KeyName' => $keyPairName]);

// Save the private key
$saveKeyLocation = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop'. "/.ssh/{$keyPairName}.pem";
file_put_contents($saveKeyLocation, $result['keyMaterial']);
```

if also your problem not solved after try this, try to use S3Client library instead Ec2Client as the Amazon wrote their samples by this client

and at last sorry because of my less details about your problem. i don't work with this library and only with my expriance about php will help you

Comment: by using echo($result->KeyMaterial);  it gives this error "Undefined property: Aws\Result::$KeyMaterial " and echo($result->data->KeyMaterial);
its also gives error i.e. cannot access private property Aws\Result::$data

Comment: @SyedCreative i edited my post for you. recheck it again

Comment: Thanks for your answer I fixed it by using ToArray() function that is 

`$data = $result->toArray();
print_r($data['KeyMaterial']);`